# Prevent checkbox being checked after taphold

Tags: jquery-mobile

I've been trying for days now, but it won't work. I have a controlgroup containing some checkboxes, which are being bound with knockout.js:

```
<div data-role="content">
    <div data-role="fieldcontain" data-bind="with:selectedList, jqmRefreshList:selectedList">
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-bind="foreach: { data: items }" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" data-mini="true">
            <input type="checkbox" data-bind="attr: {id:guid}, checked:isChecked" />
            <label data-bind="text:value, attr: {for:guid}"></label>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm using a "taphold" event, on which I want to open a popup:

```
$(document).on('taphold', '.ui-checkbox', function (event) {
    $('#listitem-page #add-listitem-popup').popup('open', { transition: 'pop' });
});
```

The popup opens normally, but the big problem is that the checkbox is being checked as well. The checkbox should only be checked on a "tap" or "vclick", which is the default behaviour and seems to work fine. The problem is that when i taphold (long touch), the popup is opened, and at the moment I release my finger from the screen, the vclick is generated and the checkbox is checked.

I tried several things (on the right location in the document):

```
event.preventDefault();
event.stopPropagation();
event.stopImmediatePropagation();
$.event.special.tap.emitTapOnTaphold = false;



.ui-checkbox {
        -webkit-touch-callout: none !important;
    }

.ui-mobile {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

in the vclick eventhandler (and the taphold eventhandler), but there seems no way to cancel the vclick from happening after I release my finger from the screen (taphold). Does anyone have suggestions? Thank you!

PS, the problem is on an Android device...

Comment: A simple solution is to uncheck the checkbox using jquery before or after the popup. Give your input type checkbox an ID, for example -- id="checkbox" -- and add the following to the taphold event   --- $('#checkbox').prop('checked', false);

Comment: Thank you, but that is not my prefered solution, since I do several things on a "checked changed" event. I'm just not able to prevent it from getting checked on Android...